# flex3: AdvancedDataGrid with many LinkButton itemrenderers getting performance issue

Tags: performance, apache-flex, flex3, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

I am facing loading time taking - performance issue due to many linkbuttons in the datagrid.

Suppose, In my page, there are 4 pod(panel) objects, and each containing ADGrid. 
As of now, for some scenario, we have to make all the datagrids columns itemrenderer as a LinkButton, except first column.
Present, i am having 21 columns and records are 10 only, so for one AdvancedDataGrid, 210 LinkButton objects been created.

Totally, for one screen, altogether 210*4(AdvancedDataGrids) = 840 LinkButton instances.

Due to this reason, i am facing performance issue, the screen is taking 30 seconds to render each object.

If i comment that itemrenderer, it is taking 20 secs around.

Ways i tried : 1) I commented all the setStyle functionalities too, bt the output is differs in 1 to 1.5 secs
2) Instead of creating LinkButton,for checking performance i used Button as renderer, and label as renderer - even though the difference is in 1 to 2 secs only.

I am very much thankful in advance for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my renderer, according to some conditions, we need to make use of **enabled = true | false,** due to this line of statement, it is taking more time to load the screen. And now, instead of enabling and disabling, i was controlling the enabled = false (which should nt allow click event triggering) and handling that respective changes in click event.